Geometry nodes, how to create mesh lines from origin to vertex points on circle
I created a circle using Geometry Nodes and placed an instance on the vertices. The number of vertices can be adjusted. Now I want to create a line from the origin to each vertex on the circle, so if the number of vertices is set to 5, there will also be 5 lines. How can I achieve this in Geometry Nodes?

Instead of just "dots" (mesh circle), you can instance a jointed mesh line with this circle, using the curve tangent and the Rotation socket of the Instance on Points node to align the mesh line towards the main circle center.

Cone with 0 height


Maybe Extrude vertices, with negative offset.

Hint, instead of a "value", it's possible to use the negative "position" (multiplied by "vector math") plugged to the "offset". This would expand the solution work in cases where you don't create the geometry or don't have a value due to  the creation complexity.

You can use a 0-height cone to produce that:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
